# Stack Exchange logo not visible in chat

Tags: bug, design, chat, logo

The one-box image of http://stackexchange.com is transparent and not visible boldly unlike the http://stackoverflow.com one-box image.

[image]

It looks clear only when you look close. Perhaps it needs the original colors of the logo to look better. Something like this

[image]

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: @KevinTinnemans Wheter the smiley made by Bhargav Rao is good enough to be on Meta or not. :)

Comment: @KevinTinnemans It is a [tag:bug] report. It implies that the SE logo is not visible and they need to rectify it.

Comment: [All the cool logos have activated stealth mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351518/the-bezos-expeditions-logo-in-the-institutional-investors-section-of-the-company). Didn't you know?