# The Bezos Expeditions logo in the Institutional Investors section of the Company page is really hard to see

Tags: feature-request, companies-page

The Institutional Investors section at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/company features the Bezos Expeditions logo. The darkest point on the logo is `#d4d4d4`, making it very hard to read on a white background:

[image: Example 1]

I appreciate that this is a different company's logo, and a better image may not be easy to obtain, but the logo they use in the header of their website is darker (`#999`) and is a lot easier to read on a white background:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Intentional understatement, perhaps? It got your attention. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray And some extra free advertising to boot!

Comment: If these subliminal manipulations are on purpose, they must be really AWSome.

Comment: I know colleagues who configured their displays in a way that light grey tones like that simply don't appear. So even though it might get your attention, there will be people who will just see a large white area. :D