# One-boxes of chat sites confusingly turn into main site links

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

Posting `chat.stackoverflow.com` or `chat.stackexchange.com` in chat will one-box these links as expected, but after the one-box the logos link to `stackoverflow.com` and `stackexchange.com` main, respectively:

[image: animgif of bug]

Either the links shouldn't one-box, or the original link targets should be kept. I assume the reason for this behaviour is that there's no specific "chat.S[OE] logo", but I find the current behaviour confusing (and buggy).

---

While we're at it: the SE logo is white for some reason, which looks weird.

Comment: For the "weird" part ... Mostly [by-design]. I asked this an year ago https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316721/stack-exchange-logo-not-visible-in-chat it seems to be ignored as I didn't see any comments from devs. (the deleted comments there are fun tho)

Comment: @BhargavRao it was ignored because chat is a low priority for them. It does not imply a [by-design] resolution. The white logo looks dreadful as currently stands.

Comment: @Zanon that's because chat is a third-grade citizen...no, hold on...